# Coronasdk: About Factory Pattern and Corona Forum

Tags: coronasdk

I am new to corona and I tried to post in forum but I do not how.
I could not find button or link liked "new thread", what should I do?

I also have a question about Factory pattern in corona.
I tried to make myImage.lua which works liked factory function.

--in myImage.lua (I created global function)

```
function a(path)

  local b = display.newImage(path)

(another setting)

  return b;

end
```

I found that when I call this function in main.lua,
the function give me just one image no matter how many time I called function.
So I guessed that this is not factory function.
I wonder that is there somehow that I can create function which return new item+different item(not reference the existed one) every times that I called

Comment: You need to register on the Corona forum before you can post.

Comment: @Douglas, Sorry that I did not mention that I have registered in Corona forum but all I got is I can see only "New User Start Here" forum. I also still cannot post anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it to a display group. That should retain the images.

```
--Global variable:
local images = display.newGroup()

function a(path)

  local b = display.newImage(path)
  (another setting)
  images:insert(b)

end
```

Oh, and you have to buy the thing before you can use the forums.

Comment: [quote]"you have to by the thing before you can use the forums."[/quote] ... you mean "buy"? Ah,... I see. Thank you for your code.